# Joining Arguments - Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to send arguments to a function and then in that function, join the arguments to make a string.

The code I'm trying

```
method send_data(\@args) {
       my $string = join('%', @args);
       print $string . '\n';
}

send_data('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
```

I know I could do it this way:

```
my @params = ('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
send_data(\@params);
```

But I prefer the first method. Without `Method::Signatures` you would do it this way:

```
sub send_data {
    my (@args) = @_;
    my $string = join('%', @args);
    print $string . '\n';
}

send_data('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
```

Help?

Comment: I don't use the `method` syntax regularly but it looks to me that the signature expects an arrayref but you are sending a list of arguments. Maybe enclosing `['test1', 'test2', 'test3']` in brackets in your 1st example helps? Anyway, please edit your question to be more precise!

Comment: @Biffen: No, it doesn't. You're thinking of assignment to a scalar variable. `my (@args) = @_` and `my @args = @_` behave identically.

Comment: @Borodin Of course. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Method::Signatures`, if you use `method` then the first parameter gets consumed as an implicit `$self` variable leaving only the remaining parameters in `@args`.

As this function isn't part of a class you should be using `func` instead of `method` and in this particular case there's no need for the `\` either:

```
func send_data(@args) {
    my $string = join('%', @args);
    print $string . '\n';
}

send_data('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
```

NB: this will also print the literal string `\n` - if you wanted an actual newline you must enclose the `\n` in double quotes instead of single quotes.